# How to Change the Web Browser activity level to "heavy" in INET (OMNeT++)?

Tags: web, networking, browser, omnet++, inet

How to Change the Web Browser activity level to "heavy" in INET (OMNeT++)? Actually I have to analyze the performance of a web browsing network by changing the activity level to heavy, but I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the .ini file and change the profile id. The following is some explanation:
[image]

You need to understand .ini language check this link for details [omnetpp manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/)